# Issue with Fireworks 8 on Vista/Windows 7 and Aero

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, aero, adobe-fireworks

When I run Fireworks 8 on Vista or Windows 7, Windows disables Aero Glass. I click on the notification bubble and get to the Aero Troubleshooter, which runs (while Fireworks is still open) and when it's done, turns Aero Glass back on and Fireworks works great. When I close and open Fireworks though, Aero Glass is disabled again.

Anyone know how I can prevent Windows from disabling Aero Glass when launching Fireworks 8?

Comment: Flash 8 also does this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an older issue](http://digg.com/software/Fireworks_8_reverts_Vista_Aero_back_to_Vista_Basic) that Adobe has still not released a patch for.

Comment: Fireworks.exe properties doesn't have the Compatibility tab. The shortcut to it in the start menu does. I set the settings you described above there and I still get Aero Basic.

Comment: The above is for Win7

Comment: they are both identical in those aspects but it doesn't appear to solve it either way.